# PYTHON Matplotlib and tkinter issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a main window working using Tkinter. When a button is pressed it brings up a new window containing a plot, a close button, and some checkboxes down the right hand side. (only one is shown for brevity)

```
def display_graph():
     # Generate some random example data
     x = [0.00, 3.00, 6.00, 9.00, 12.00,15.00,18.00,24.00,24.00]
     y = [random.randint(5, 10) for _ in range(9)]

     # Create a line plot
     fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     ax.plot(x, y)
     ax.set_xlabel('Time')
     ax.set_ylabel('Values')
     ax.set_title('Sensor Data Graph')

     # Create a new tkinter window for the plot
     graph_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
     graph_window.title('Sensor Data Graph')

     # Set window attributes to cover the entire screen
     graph_window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

     # Embed the matplotlib figure in the tkinter window
     canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graph_window)
     canvas.draw()
     canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

     # Create a custom close button in the plot window's title bar
     close_button = tk.Button(
        graph_window,
        text="X",
        bg="red",
        fg="white",
        relief="flat",
        activebackground="red",
        activeforeground="white",
        command=lambda: close_graph_window(graph_window)
     )
     close_button.place(x=graph_window.winfo_width() - 25, y=0, width=25, height=25)

     # Create checkbox
     graph_window.checkboxtemp = tk.Checkbutton(graph_window, text="Temp")
     graph_window.checkboxtemp.place(x=graph_window.winfo_screenwidth() - 79, y=30, width=70, height=30)
```

When the window is closed using a destroy() command which destroys that window and brings back the main window

The issue is, I assumed when the window is closed using 'destroy', it deletes all the widgets on that window BUT when I re-open the graph page next time, the checkbox states are preserved, ie. If I click on a checkbox, destroy, then re-open the plot, the checkbox is still checked..

I thought maybe it was global so I renamed checkboxtemp to graph_window.checkboxtemp but no difference..

Any idea why the checkboxes preserve their values?

I tried non globalising it, I expected the checkboxes to be cleared and go back to default value. (un checked) when the plot window is created again after a destroy()

Comment: Checkbuttons don't store their own state at all, they rely on a Tkinter Var object (specified by the `variable=` option) to store it.  I have no idea what the default behavior is when you fail to do this - apparently a Var is being created for you, with some auto-generated name that is the same for both instances of your window, so that the state gets reused.  Explicitly create your own `IntVar` (or possibly a different Var type) and you won't have this problem.